# Django ORM: Combine exlude with not in filter

Tags: django, django-orm

For this (strongly simplified) Django model setup:

```
class A(models.Model)

class B(models.Model)
  a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True)

class C(models.Model)
  b = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to make sure that for a query on C, no related objects that are not [a1,a2] are part of a query.

Something like:

```
qs = C.objects.exclude(b__a__NOT_in=[a1, a2]).
```

What I'm searching for is **not**

```
qs = C.objects.filter(b__a__in=[a1, a2])
```

as my foreign keys are nullable, and I would also like to fetch cases in which any of the fks on the way is null.

What's the most elegant way to solve this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want C instances for which `b` is null or `b__a` is null or `b__a` is one of `(a1, a2)`. A possible solution here is to [use the `models.Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) to build an `or` query, ie:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q(b__a__in=[a1, a2]) | Q(b__a__isnull=True) | Q(b__isnull=True)
qs = C.objects.filter(query)
```

or just ["OR" querysets directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#or):

```
qs = C.objects.filter(b__a__in=[a1, a2]) | C.objects.filter(b__a__isnull=True) | C.objects.filter(b__isnull=True)
```

which will yield the very same SQL query but is a bit more verbose...

Comment: This is correct! Thank you!  However what I'm searching for is a solution where I do not have to explicitly exclude all empty FK cases, rather a shorter `qs = C.objects.exclude(b__a__NOT_in=[a1, a2])` like statement

Comment: What's the problem with adding the two possible cases where the FKs can be null?

Comment: If you exclude `NOT IN [a1, a2]`, you exclude null values so you have to include them again if you want them, no way around that. Then you're better off with Bruno's solution which avoids the double negative and is much more readable.

Comment: @elke "what I'm searching for is a solution where I do not have to explicitly **exclude** all empty FK case" => I assume you meant "include" here ? Else I obviously failed to understand your specs...